# What is diiference between Root Directory and Parent Directory in Jsp?

Tags: css, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

Using request dispatcher i forwarded the request to new Jsp page. The stylesheet is not loading when i use the following the lines

```
 < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
```

But Stylesheet is loading when i replace this line with

```
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=request.getcontextpath()+"/css/style.css>
```

Can someone explain the difference clearly. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `../` just means go up one directory, the other gets the root of your context. First one is relative and the other is not.

Comment: You can do the second one with `./`.

Comment: @Andrew Without seeing the folder structure of the project, how can you determine that the css folder is inside the current working directory? (which is what `./` indicates)

Comment: You can't necessarily do the second one with `./`. I originally misunderstood the return value of `request.getContextPath()`.